# Where does this "_.startsWith" come from?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am trying to understand the following code from the [browserify-css](https://github.com/cheton/browserify-css#2-how-do-i-load-font-and-image-files-from-node_modules) repo:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var path = require('path');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var sourceStream = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var fse = require('fs-extra');

var bundleStream = browserify()
    .add('src/index.js')
    .transform(require('browserify-css'), {
        rootDir: 'src',
        processRelativeUrl: function(relativeUrl) {
            var stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath = function(url) {
                return url.split('?')[0].split('#')[0];
            };
            var rootDir = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src');
            var relativePath = stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath(relativeUrl);
            var queryStringAndHash = relativeUrl.substring(relativePath.length);

            //
            // Copying files from '../node_modules/bootstrap/' to 'dist/vendor/bootstrap/'
            //
            var prefix = '../node_modules/';
            if (_.startsWith(relativePath, prefix)) {
                var vendorPath = 'vendor/' + relativePath.substring(prefix.length);
                var source = path.join(rootDir, relativePath);
                var target = path.join(rootDir, vendorPath);

                gutil.log('Copying file from ' + JSON.stringify(source) + ' to ' + JSON.stringify(target));
                fse.copySync(source, target);

                // Returns a new path string with original query string and hash fragments
                return vendorPath + queryStringAndHash;
            }

            return relativeUrl;
        }
    })
    .bundle();

bundleStream
    .pipe(sourceStream(bundleFile))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(browserifyConfig.dest));
```

I don't understand the part

```
_.startsWith(relativePath, prefix)
```

Where is the underscore coming from? It's supposed to be javascript executed by a task runner. I've found that in the NodeJS REPL the underscore character outputs the result of the last executed expression, but that functionality can't be used inside scripts. It's also not an underscore.js instance because it is not being declared anywhere. `startsWith` is a String method.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is using the [lodash library](https://lodash.com/). You can see in [this section](https://github.com/cheton/browserify-css#processrelativeurl) of the readme that they're importing lodash with `var _ = require('lodash');`